# Update Column by Parsing String from Other Column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I would like to create a new column in a MYSQL table based on the string values in an existing column.

My strategy is to first create an empty column and then update the values in the new column based on values in the existing column. However, I am stumbling on how to parse the string in order to extract the correct values.

The string is of the form 1.1.25. I want to extract the value before the first period and the value between the two periods and put these in new columns.

```
mytable
id|actsceneline|text
1 |1.1.1       |How are you.
1 |1.1.2       |Not bad. You?
```

To create the new empty column

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD COLUMN act VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
ADD COLUMN scene VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
```

To change the values in the new columns, I imagine I would do something like:

```
UPDATE mytable SET act = '1',scene = 1
```

And then use MYSQL string functions such as `instr` or `substr` or regex to extract the values and update the new columns as in.

```
UPDATE mytable SET act = 
SELECT SUBSTR(actsceneline, 1, LOCATE('.', text)) FROM mytable
```

However, I'm struggling with how to extract the values from the string.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Well struggle to show us what you have got so far, give us a starter for 10

Comment: This is a long way from rocket science! Do the testing using a simple select query until you get the text manipulation correct, then make it into an update query

Comment: Q1: Why do you need a VARCHAR(100) to hold a `1`? Pretty sure nothing has that many acts or scenes. Q2) Why do you use a VARCHAR at all to hold an integer?

Comment: The original data set uses strings. The act and scene could be integers but strings should suffice.

Comment: You realise the `varchar(5)` could hold `99,999` acts or scenes so as John Lennon would say, Imaging all the acts you could get into `varchar(100)` :)

Comment: That's correct but unrelated to the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET act = SUBSTRING_INDEX(actsceneline, '.', 1), 
    scene = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(actsceneline, '.', 2), '.', -1);
```

Result given your data:

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+-------+
| id | actsceneline | text          | act | scene |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+-------+
|  1 | 1.1.1        | How are you.  | 1   | 1     |
|  2 | 1.1.2        | Not bad. You? | 1   | 1     |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create a select and what you want to update.
create a new table from your existing table.
"create table destinationtablename
select * from sourcetable;"
then work on your destinationtablename.
All work finished then check twice before update to original table or you can also take backup of your data by creating new table.